# Filter rows using column values as condition for another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

This is pretty tricky. Let's say I have, for example, a first dataset `df`:

```
sample   id                  name
1        ID200,ID300,ID299   first
2        ID2,ID123           second
3        ID90                third
```

And a second dataset `df_1`:

```
ids       condition
ID200        y
ID300        n
ID299        n
ID2          y
ID123        y
ID90         n
```

I have to filter, from the first dataset, all the rows in which all ID values ​​satisfy a condition on the second table, like `y`.
So the filtering in this example should give:

```
 sample   id                  name
 2        ID2,ID123           second
```

I was thinking to use something like:

```
new_df = df %>%
  filter(grepl('ID', id), df_1$condition == 'y')
```

But obviously I need something different, can you give me some clues?

Edit: As I said in the comment, what happens if I have df's id column populated with other text, like this?

```
sample   id                                         name
1              ID = ID200,ID300,ID299,abcd          first
2              ID = ID2,ID123, dfg                  second
3              ID = ID90, text                      third
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit inelegant, but this would give you the final condition status of each sample.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(sample = c(1, 2, 3),
             id = c("ID200,ID300,ID299", "ID2,ID123", "ID90"),
             name = c("first", "second", "third"))

df_1 <- tibble(ids = c("ID200", "ID300", "ID299", "ID2", "ID123", "ID90"),
               condition = c("y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n"))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(ids = str_split(id, ",")) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  inner_join(df_1, by = "ids") %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  summarise(condition = min(condition))
```

You could then join that to the to the original data frame for filtering.

```
filtered <- inner_join(df, df2, by = "sample") %>%
  filter(condition == "y")
```

Comment: I'll try both answers asap, but I have another question: if my Id column is populated not only with id strings, for example: "ID = ID2, ID123, other text", what can I do?

Comment: Then that information should be in your original question :)

Comment: Ok, I figured it out using the function grepl to filter the columns that contains the substring 'ID'. Btw I'm having some problem returning to the original format. I'll try this evening and will edit the original post with the code.

Comment: @Sean Raffuse The code worked like a charm. I didn't need to filter for ID, my bad. Btw, can you explain me the `summarise(condition = min(condition))` part? I don't get why you use the `min()` function

Comment: I used `min()` because the two possible values were 'y' and 'n', and you wanted to find all the samples where condition for all ids was 'y'. If a sample contains any 'n' values, then `min()` will return 'n'.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by tidying `df` so as `id` contains one observation per row:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(id)

  sample    id   name
1      1 ID200  first
2      1 ID300  first
3      1 ID299  first
4      2   ID2 second
5      2 ID123 second
6      3  ID90  third
```

The same operation, followed by a join with `df_1`:

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(id) %>% 
  left_join(df_1, by = c("id" = "ids"))

  sample    id   name condition
1      1 ID200  first         y
2      1 ID300  first         n
3      1 ID299  first         n
4      2   ID2 second         y
5      2 ID123 second         y
6      3  ID90  third         n
```

Now you can group on `sample` and filter for cases where the only condition is "y":

```
new_df <- df %>% 
  separate_rows(id) %>% 
  left_join(df_1, by = c("id" = "ids")) %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>% 
  filter(condition == "y", 
         n_distinct(condition) == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
  sample id    name   condition
   <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>    
1      2 ID2   second y        
2      2 ID123 second y
```

If you really want to transform back to the original format with comma-separated ids in a column:

```
library(purrr)
new_df %>% 
  nest(id) %>% 
  mutate(newid = map_chr(data, ~paste(.$id, collapse = ","))) %>% 
  select(sample, id = newid, name)

  sample id        name  
   <int> <chr>     <chr> 
1      2 ID2,ID123 second
```

Comment: This code worked too, but I had some problem on returning to the original format, maybe because I have much more columns, I don't know. I'll try to fix and make this work. By the way, thank you very much!